# Remove active class from bootstrap 4 closed tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

Thanks to @Eric G,  I have a tab pane that toggles open / close when you click on a tab. Now that the tab pane toggles (js removes active class) how would I also remove the active class of the tab itself? I have styling on the the .active class indicated an "active tab". I want to remove that class when the tab has been toggled close.

My Example: http://codepen.io/anycircle/pen/dNMPrW

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#panel-search" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-parent="#panel-container" data-target="#panel-search">Tab</a>
</li>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="panel-search">
Tab Pane
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-link").click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase()).toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-link").click(function(){
          var me = $(this);
          var panel = $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase());
          if(me.hasClass('active')){
             me.removeClass('active');
            panel.removeClass('active');     
                return false;
          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the previously selected tab's information from the event data with e.relatedTarget. You can use the hash to target the tap pane class with the same id.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab',
            function (e) {
                $('div' + e.relatedTarget.hash + '.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
            });
```